# 'const_get': uninitialized constant View (NameError) after running script with typo

Tags: ruby

I ran the following script by mistake:

```
rails g devise views
```

Then I get this error whenever I attempt to run any rails command:

```
`const_get': uninitialized constant View (NameError)
```

Any ideas how I can repair this, Stack Community? I can't find any references to View, so don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to find an answer for this myself.

When you accidentally install a new Model as I have done here in the code

```
rails g devise views
```

A route is automatically generated. To get the application working again, just remove the route

```
devise_for Views
```

from the route file at:

```
[YOUR_APPLICATION]/config/routes.rb
```